# International SEO with the same language?

Tags: seo, internationalization, hreflang

My company is creating an international version of our site at international.example.com. We are located in the US with our main site at example.com but offer different slightly different products internationally.

Ideally, we would have Hreflang tags for different versions in different languages, however, it's going to be an almost duplicate site besides a few different SKUs in the same language. The language and content on the site is going to be in English. Again, the only content changing is a few different SKU names and content. We won't be showing the pricing.

The subdomain is our only option right now. Should we implement Hreflang tags even if both languages are English and only the content is slightly different? Or just having canonicals should be fine?

How should we handle this? Thanks!

Comment: when you say 'just having canonicals should be fine?'  what was your planned canonical set up?

Comment: @Max My planned set up was having only canonical tags. I'm trying to figure out if the hreflangs are needed in my case.